# JavaScript/NodeJs - TypeError: Cannot set property 'validation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna validate the user form input and I just write this code but actually there is one error I could not fix and I don't understand why it's here (error).

```
let User = (data) => {
    this.data = data
    this.errors = []
}
User.prototype.validation = () => {
    if(this.data.username == ""){
        this.errors.push("You must* provide a username")
    }else if(this.data.email == ""){
        this.errors.push("You must* provide the email address for you account")
    }else if(this.data.password == ""){
        this.errors.push("You must* provide the password for your account")
    }
}
User.prototype.register = () => {
    // step #1 validate user data
    this.validation()
    // step #2 only if there are no validation errors
    // then save the user data into a database
}

module.exports = User
```

and the error that I got.

```
User.prototype.validation = () => {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'validation' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\40sherrin\Desktop\application\models\User.js:5:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\40sherrin\Desktop\application\controllers\userController.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
```

Comment: Arrow functions exist to solve a particular problem: _access the enclosing lexical `this`_. Constructor functions rely on receiving `this` when invoked with the `new` operator as an object that inherits from the function's prototype. That's why arrow functions cannot be used as constructors, and if you use them as `prototype` methods, they won't be able to access the object instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use arrow functions for [defining a constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to
>   a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to
>   the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. **Arrow function
>   expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as
>   constructors**.

**Use of prototype property**

> Arrow functions do not have a prototype property.

```
let User = function (data) {
    this.data = data
    this.errors = []
}
User.prototype.validation = function() {
    if(this.data.username == ""){
        this.errors.push("You must* provide a username")
    }else if(this.data.email == ""){
        this.errors.push("You must* provide the email address for you account")
    }else if(this.data.password == ""){
        this.errors.push("You must* provide the password for your account")
    }
}
User.prototype.register = function() {
    // step #1 validate user data
    this.validation()
    // step #2 only if there are no validation errors
    // then save the user data into a database
}
```

So use `function` instead or ES6 Classes.

```js
class User {

   constructor(data) {
       this.data = data
       this.errors = []
   }

   validation() {
      // ...
   }

   register() {
      this.validation();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[fat arrow functions do not have prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).